# Showing the function to be indentically zero according to the given constraint

Tags: calculus, functions

Show that if $f(x)$ is continuous on [0,1] and $\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(t^{2}\right)-t\right)^{2} d t=0$ then $f(x) = √x$

> My procedure was that as f(x) is continuous on [0,1] so is f(x^2) [i dont have a proof of this but i am assuming it will be because x^2 is continuous in [0,1] ? Next a function which is continuous and $\geq 0$ $\forall$ [0,1]  giving integral to be 0 in that region means everywhere in that region it has to be 0 only because if it was not so then it would need to have some negative value to compensate the positive area in some region which is contradiction to intial assumptions ?

Comment: Note, that composition of continuous functions is continuous. Your argument looks right. You could argument like: if the integrand wasn't identical zero it would be $>0$ in a little neighbourhood around some $x \in [0,1]$ since it is continuous, so the integral would be greater than $0$.

Comment: I see compositon... . Thanks for confirming . Nice point @psl2Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The composition of continuous functions is continuous. We are given $f$ is continuous; and we could take for granted the fact that $g: t \mapsto t^2$ is continuous or else briefly notice that $|t-a|^2 \leq |t-a|$ for all $t, a \in [0,1]$ (as $0 \leq |t-a| \leq 1$ on $[0,1]^2$).
2. Let $h(t)=(f(t^2)-t)^2$. So $h$ is continuous for reasons discussed in (1), and $h(t) \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$.
3. Assume there is $a \in [0,1]$ such that $h(a) \neq 0$. Then there is $r>0$ so that $h(a)=r$. Consider $\varepsilon=\frac{r}{2}$. Since $h$ is continuous, there is $\delta>0$ so that $t \in (a-\delta, a+\delta) \cap [0,1]$ implies that
   $$\frac{r}{2}=h(a)-\varepsilon<h(x)<h(a)+\varepsilon.$$
   By monotonicity we have
   $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(t^{2}\right)-t\right)^{2} d t \geq \frac{r}{2} \cdot \delta >0.$$
4. Since our assumption leads to a contradiction, it follows that we have $f(t^2)-t=0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ which is equivalent to saying that $f(t)=f(|t|)=\sqrt{t}$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: By monotonicity, I mean $\int_0^1 h(t) dt \geq \int_0^1 h(t)  \displaystyle{\chi_{B(a, \delta)}}dt $ as $h(t) \geq  h(t) \displaystyle{\chi_{B(a, \delta)}} \geq 0$.

Comment: In the last step we gave justification that f(|t|) =√t , so for t in [0,1] as we have |t|=t hence f(t)=√t?  If right , consider a case of f(t^2) = t^2 , when take root we would get f(|t| ) = |t| in [-1,1] , in that case will we say as function cannot have same value at one point so we will reject one out of it and say that f(t) = either +t or -t for t belonging to [0,1] or +t only is possible?

Comment: The understanding you express in your first question is indeed correct. If $f(t^2)=t^2$ for all $t \in [-1,1]$, then we have $f(|t|)=|t|$, and so either $f(t)=t$ or else $f(t)=|t|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: **Note**:  in my previous comment, it should be $f(t)=\pm t$ or else $f(t)=|t|$.  $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  $  /errata

Comment: Yeah understood thanks again :) i was expecting that onlt so didnt ask again